# Get Facebook Graph API extended access token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can get the posts I need from a Facebook Page using this code in PHP:

```
$token = "ACCESS_TOKEN";
$data = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/feed?access_token=".$token);
$data = json_decode($data, true);
```

However, the access token it just last 1 hour.
I saw that it's possible to request a long live token that lasts 60 days, but stills not so clear for me with a good example.

Do you guys know a good example using PHP?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/roadmap/completed-changes/offline-access-removal), you need to pass the short-lived access-token with app secret and in return you will get the Long-lived access-token

> *To get the long-lived user access_token simply pass your own client_id (your app_id), your app_secret, and the non-expired,
>   short-lived access_token to the endpoint below. You will be returned a
>   new long-lived user access_token; this access_token will exist in
>   addition to the short-lived access_token that was passed into the
>   endpoint.*

**Code Sample**

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?             
    client_id=APP_ID&
    client_secret=APP_SECRET&
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
    fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use like that  `$accessToken = $session->getAccessToken();
  $longLivedAccessToken = $accessToken->extend();`

then check access token with url.